# PhoneGap InAppBrowser: Cannot open link with "%" character

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova, webview

I am using PhoneGap 2.4 for my iOS project.

When I want to open external URL's in a new webview layer via `window.open(url, "_blank");`, this works well for "simple" URL's, e.g. "http://www.google.com".

**BUT**

more complicated URL's which include whitespace and special characters are a problem. To avoid this, I URL-encode them via this JavaScript-call:

```
url = encodeURIComponent(url);
```

This won't work with the InAppBrowser plugin. Instead I get an error message saying:

> webView:didFailLoadWithError - The operation couldn't be completed.
>   (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)

So, I looked into this and I noticed that the call to `window.open(url, "_blank");` fails with this error message **if the url contains the "%" character**, e.g. if a whitespace character gets encoded to "%20".

How can I work around this? Isn't this a bug?

---

**Update:** I just tested the same app on Android with PhoneGap 2.3. Works like a charm. So it's either an iOS issue or a problem with the latest PhoneGap release which is 2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn, I just found the issue. There was a single unencoded whitespace in my url. I replaced it with "%20" and now it works.

I guess I am getting old :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the % with an escape key

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I added `url = url.replace(/%/g, '\\%');` which results in a leading `\\` before every % but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using encodeURI instead (see the Quick Example):
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open

Comment: No effect, already tried that. Besides that `escape()` also seems to not solve the problem.